# Why doesn't [kill -s SIGUSR1] work inside script but works on command line? (re: invalid signal specification)

Tags: shell-script, signals

I'm trying to write a shell script (/bin/sh) that includes a command-line option to send SIGUSR1 to a process:

```
my_command() {
        printf "Sending SIGUSR1: "
        kill -s SIGUSR1 `pidof my_process`
        [ $? = 0 ] && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
}
```

However, it fails:

```
/etc/init.d# ./S40test my_command
Sending SIGUSR1: ./S40test: line 39: kill: SIGUSR1: invalid signal specification
FAIL
```

However, if I run the command on the command-line:

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 `pidof my_process`
```

...then it works fine.

I've also changed pidof my_process to use the actual process number but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try with `kill -USR1`. Not all shells support that `kill -s SIGFOO` form.

Comment: According to the POSIX spec, it should be `kill -s signal_name`, where `signal_name` is *without* the `SIG` prefix.

Comment: @UncleBilly: write that as an answer?

Comment: @UncleBilly That worked!  Thanks!  Do you want to submit it and I'll mark it as the answer?

Comment: You're mixing `bash`'s built-in implementation of `kill` that you're using on the command line with the POSIX variant `/bin/kill` used in your script

Answer (score 3):

Use `kill -s USR1 <pid>` or `kill -USR1 <pid>` instead.

According to the POSIX [spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), the former is the standard form:

> `-s  signal_name`
> Specify the signal to send, using one of the symbolic names defined in the `<signal.h>` header. Values of signal_name shall be recognized in a case-independent fashion, **without the `SIG` prefix**.
> ...
> `-signal_name`
> [XSI] Equivalent to `-s signal_name`.

But the latter is the one almost universally supported (even in non-posix shells like `csh`).

Only some shells support the non-standard `kill -s SIGFOO` form instead of `kill -s FOO` with their `kill` built-ins; In particular, `dash` (which on Debian and Ubuntu is the `/bin/sh` used to execute scripts), does NOT support it.